# Free particle in quantum mechanics (Pauli principle?)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, wavefunction, electrons, pauli-exclusion-principle

By what is a state of a free particle defined? For a bound electron for instance it is fully described by the quantum numbers $n,l,m$ and the respective state $|n,l,m\rangle$. But by what is the free particle (electron) defined? I'd guess energy and spin maybe?

From that point on I ask myself: Since a bound electron is defined by $|n,l,m\rangle$ there is the Pauli exclusion principle excluding two or more electrons with the same $n,l,m$. Is it also possible to formulate a similar Pauli exclusion for free particles?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to only ask about energy eigenstates? There isn't a single state for free particles. Similarly not all bound states can be described as $|n,l,m\rangle$.

Comment: Well, yes energy eigenstates because they form a full basis of the Hilbert space and thereofre yield a full description of the particle. To my understanding, we could also choose other states as long as they form a full basis set.

Answer (score 1):

The energy eigenstates for a free particle are simply given by their momentum vector $\vec{k}$ (or $\vec{p}=\hbar \vec{k}$ if you prefer). These states are all orthogonal in the sense that states of different $\vec{k}$ have zero overlap and any wavefunction can be expressed as a linear combination of them. Thus for fermions with no internal degrees of freedom, what Pauli would forbid is two fermions having exactly the same momentum.

For the case of electrons, they do also have an additional 'internal' degree of freedom due to their spin. So you can have two electrons in a spin singlet state with the same momentum, but not 3.

(Note: I am intentionally ignoring any subtleties about the fact that momentum eigenstates are not normalisable, which is a much longer story.)

Comment: To describe a real free electron, one has to use the wavepacket model which can represent a free electron with a width in its momentum/energy  in probability of measuring it. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html

Comment: So if I get it right, you say that the state of a free electron is defined by the energy (or momentum) and the spin?

Comment: By the momentum, not the energy. There are multiple states with the same energy and different momenta. It is momentum that distinguishes states.

Comment: @annav I agree that a real electron will not be found in a pure momentum eigenstate ever, but that doesn't mean you can't label a basis by momentum.

Comment: You can label it, but it is not labeling that is being excluded by Pauli Pinricpe, it is occupying the same level

Comment: @annav I'm not really clear what we're disagreeing on. Pauli forbids a two particle wavefunction from factoring into a tensor product of identical wavefunctions. That includes as a special case the fact that two free (spinless, for simplicity) fermions are not able to both be in the same momentum eigenstate, which is the closest analogue of the discussion of $|n,l,m\rangle$ in atomic physics.

Comment: It is just semantic confusion, it is an energy eigenstate, because it is a solution of the hamiltonian,. For a bound in a potential particle momentum has no meaning, as it is orbitals (probability loci) not orbits in atoms. For a free fermion=spin 1/2 particle, momentum has a meaning taken into the wavepacket model, but momentum and energy are related through the mass and the four vector, so I am talking of energy eigenstates.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly!!

If you have solved, the free particle problem in quantum mechanics. We the eigen state look like
$$|E,+\rangle =|p=\sqrt{2mE}\rangle$$
$$|E,-\rangle =|p=-\sqrt{2mE}\rangle $$
In the system of two electrons, you need to take account of  Coulomb potential. So the eigenstate would look pretty different (further it's 3D problem).

But still, they have Pauli's principle (particle should be fermion). Not just free particle, any system of particles obeys Pauli exclusion principle.

Comment: any system of **Fermions** obeys Pauli exclusion principle.

Comment: Okay, so by what is the Pauli Principle of free particles determined? From those states you wrote down I'd guess it is just the energy then? (Or maybe also the spin)

Could we say then: "In the case of a free electron, there are not two or more electrons with the same energy."
?

Answer (score 0):

The same question can be raised for the conduction [band in solids](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html), where the electrons are "free" all over the lattice. The obvious answer is that there is practically  a continuum in the energy levels available to conduction band electrons, so there is no real  exclusion as far as the accuracy of energy levels goes. Of course there will be a small delta(E) that will keep the Pauli exclusion principle.

The same is true for free particles in space,their wavefunction has to be modeled as a [wavepacket](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html) of frequencies which means , if two same fermions meet in space (even if it is two electrons in an accelerator beam) their wavefunctions can easily occupy other energy levels, and obey the Pauli exclusion ( not to forget how hard it is to get small errors on beams).

So no measurable effects can come from the exclusion, the way they can in atomic construction.

Comment: Thank you for that. But what about a free electron gas for instance? There, the Fermi surface for example indicates a Puli principle that forbids more than two electrons per state and a sphere in the k-space arises?

Comment: The energy levels of a free electron gas, will also be practically a continuum, and within the individual wave-packet wave-function of electrons ( if considered "free", ignoring coulomb repulsion) there will be no problem in fulfilling the pauli principle without affecting the kinematics, (within errors of measurement)

Comment: Okay thank you. Where do I go wrong when I think of the electron gas and the Fermi sphere which is obviously affecting the kinematics?

Comment: from what I see of the models, there are a large number of energy states, and if solved quantum mechanically  as a non interaction gas of fermions  my argument above should hold. In any case for any statistical ensemble it is inevitable that the number of energy levels approaches a contiunum.,

Comment: This seems to be ignoring the existence of a fermi level, as the OP has commented. Although the spacing goes to zero in the thermodynamic limit, so does the number of fermions you are trying to fit in. All the states whose energy is beloe $\epsilon_F$ are actually occupied.

Comment: So to conclude: As jacob said: A state of a free particle is determined by energy (or momentum) and by spin and there is in fact a Pauli principle, resulting in the fermi level. Would you guys agree to that?