# Does Pauli exclusion principle put a limit on the number of overlapping fermions?

Tags: fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

It seems there should be no limit to the number of electrons that can have overlapping probability clouds. They repel each other due to charge, but if there were some other force like gravity holding them together, this could be overcome. And we might consider neutral fermions.

The EP doesn't allow fermions of the same type (?) with the **exactly** the same state. If we have approximately the same state, then there's no problem. Of course there might be a finite number of states and these get filled, as in atoms or solids.

Is the word "exact" appropriate? You could have a continuum of states or a discrete set of states.

Answer (score 3):

To make the terminology of "the same type" or "approximately the same" more precise, one should think what constitutes different states? The key is orthogonality. Consider the modes that can exist in some potential well (think of an atom). These modes are all mutually orthogonal. If I represent a fermion having one of these modes as $|\psi_n\rangle$, then the orthogonality is represented by
$$ \langle\psi_m|\psi_n\rangle = \delta_{m,n} . $$
It turns out that the same is true for any system, even free space. In all such systems one can specify a set of modes that are mutually orthogonal. What the exclusion principle says is that two fermions cannot have the same mode. It is only when their modes are mutually orthogonal that they can exist in the same space simultaneously.

Comment: So, same mode equals same state and if you impose the requirement that the total wave function be antisymmetric, then when we take the product of two states and (anti)symmetrize (which we do because the particles are identical) we get a 0 wave function.  But this also would apply if each electron is in a superposition of energy eigenstates. The key here is that they can't be in the same state.

Comment: Yes, when you combine two fermions you get a boson. That is what happens for instance in superconductivity.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of overlapping wavefunctions is simple and easy to picture, but it is fundamentally incorrect.  To illustrate the concept, consider first the case of two distinguishable particles in 1D.

The wavefunction of a single particle is a square-integrable function $\psi:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb C$.  A particle localized near some point $x=a$ might have a wavefunction which look like this:

[image]

If we add a second particle localized near $x=-a$, then we might expect the wavefunction of the system to look like this:

[image]

But that's wrong.  The wavefunction of the 2-particle system is a function of *two* coordinates - one for each particle - and would look like this:

[image]

The probability amplitude is only appreciable for $x\approx -a$ and $y \approx a$, which we can interpret as meaning that the first particle is localized near $-a$ and the second near $+a$.

---

Now consider the case of indistinguishable, spinless fermions.  This imposes the additional requirement that the total wavefunction be antisymmetric.  The wavefunction I plotted above is $\psi_0(x,y) = e^{-(x+1)^2}\cdot e^{-(y-1)^2}$, which is clearly does not satisfy this requirement; we can modify it by defining $\psi(x,y)= \frac{\psi_0(x,y)-\psi_0(y,x)}{2}$, which looks like this:

[image]

By definition of antisymmetry, $\psi(x,x)=0$ so the probability amplitude corresponding to two fermions having the same position vanishes.  This implies that the probability of finding both particles in the box $[x,x+\epsilon]$ goes to zero as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ *faster* than $\epsilon$ itself.

---

So the lesson here is that given any two single-particle wavefunctions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$, we can construct a two-particle fermionic wavefunction $\psi(x,y)=\psi_1(x)\psi_2(y)-\psi_1(y)\psi_2(x)$.  As long as $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are linearly independent - so one is not merely a constant multiple of another - this yields an admissible state for the 2-fermion system.  By extension, any $N$ single particle states can be combined to form an admissible $N$-particle fermionic state as long as they are all linearly independent of one another.

Finally, I should note that real fermions - such as elections - are *not* spinless.  Electrons are spin-1/2 particles, so their wavefunctions are really 2-component spinors.  In this case, it's possible that the spatial part of the wavefunction be symmetric while the spin part is antisymmetric, or vice-versa.  I neglected this because it adds complexity to the computations without appreciably changing the message.

Comment: The total wave function must be antisymmetric for fermions, and that includes spin. In the above case, you are ignoring spin. A particle without 1/2 spin can't be a fermion.  Two ideas: one is that you have a total wave function with many coordinates as you describe, and on the other hand we talk as if different particles have  a state assigned to them individually and we talk about those states overlapping. The way out is to remember that the requirement of a system of N fermions is that the wave function is anti-symmetric under the exchange two particles. The EP is a consequence of this.

Comment: But I understand the demonstration. If you assume the requirement that the wave function must be antisymmetric, and you ignore spin, then amplitude of measuring a state where both particles are in the same location would be zero. Just a minor technical point: the probability of finding a point particle at any particular point should be zero, no? We should be talking about the probabilities of a particle appearing with in a certain region of space.

Comment: @yalis I've cleaned up my answer a bit.  There's nothing wrong with having spinless fermions as a toy model.  This is not compatible with relativity as per the spin-statistics theorem, but that's unimportant in understanding the fundamental nature of the exclusion principle.  Real fermions have half-integer spin (not just spin-1/2), but that just adds complexity to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems there should be no limit to the number of electrons that can have overlapping probability clouds. They repel each other due to charge,

In bound states there is no repulsion as seen in macroscopic charges. The potential used for the solution of the bound state takes care of that repulsion in the  $Ψ$ wave function, and the orbitals are the probability loci of finding the electron at a specific (x,y,z,t) given by $Ψ^*Ψ$. Take a negatiively ionized h[ydrogen atom's orbitals](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html). The n and l quantum numbers of [the wavefunctions](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html) at the bottom, the spin ($m^l$) shown with the arrows.

[image: Horb]

For each energy level two electrons can sit with the same quantum numbers with opposite spin. If it were not for the Pauli exclusion principle the number would not be limited to two. In order to hold more electron one has to go to higher values of the n and l quantum numbers.

The "exact" is appropriate because quantum numbers are exact. Two fermions have to have at least one quantum number different to be able to sit at the same energy level .
[In my  answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/633946/free-particle-in-quantum-mechanics-pauli-principle/634170#634170) to a similar question I discuss the "free" case.

Comment: Makes sense. The comment "In bound states there is no repulsion as seen in macroscopic charges" strikes me as something that needs expansion. But that's a different question.

Comment: The n,l.m wavfefunctions are found putting the 1/r potential in the corresponding quantum mechanical equation. The Ψ functional form depends on the appropriate  1/r potential .(coulomb)

Answer (score 1):

You can pile up N non-interacting fermions, and you will get a continuum energy spectrum, say, from zero to $E_F$, where $E_F$ is a Fermi energy.